# How to replace floor to ceil

Tags: fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

After severals days I come up with the following formula (here `>>` is a right bit shift, `x` and `N` are integers, `N >= 0`). And you can just assume that it is correct.

[image]

I've got a feeling that right part could be reduced to the following form:

[image]

I spend several days trying to figure out the way, but still have no results

Comment: The second formula is not always correct, you can plug in random numbers to check. Find a better representation of the first expression, you are getting close

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng Interesting.  With $N=3,$ I tried $x=9, x=8,$ and $x=7$.  All 3 times, the two formulas matched each other, re the 2nd formula has *ceiling* and first formula has *floor*.  Do you have a counterexample in mind?

Comment: @ĐàoMinhDũng I can post proof that first formula is correct, it's just unbelievably long. My point is to find the answer how to convert left part to right (from second formula)

Comment: @user2661923 Oh I did not see the right notation, I see it now, let me think a little bit

Comment: I am only focusing on the floor to ceiling conversion.  Re that conversion, the approach in my first comment gives a reasonable guideline for proving that the conversion is accurate for any $N$ and $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two cases.

In the first case, if $A$ is divisible by $B$. Then $\dfrac AB$ is an integer and

$$\left\lfloor\frac AB\right\rfloor = \frac AB = \left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil,$$

but $\dfrac{A - 1}B < \dfrac AB$ and

$$\left\lfloor\frac{A - 1}B\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac AB\right\rfloor - 1
 = \left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil - 1.$$

In the second case, $A$ is not divisible by $B.$ Then

$$\left\lfloor\frac{A - 1}B\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac AB\right\rfloor
 = \left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil - 1.$$

In either case,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{A - 1}B\right\rfloor = \left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil - 1$$
so
$$\left\lfloor\frac{A - 1}B\right\rfloor + 1 = \left\lceil\frac AB\right\rceil.$$

Let $A = x$ and $B = 2^N,$ and you have your result.

---

The proof above is closely related to one you have already seen, so as a bonus,
here is a proof of the original formula.

For an arbitrary positive integer $x,$
we assume that $-x$ (a negative number)
is represented by a two's-complement binary integer
in a storage location that is $L$ bits wide, where $2^{L - 1} \geq x.$
The bits in this storage location are then exactly the same as the unsigned binary integer representation of $2^L - x$ and the leftmost bit is a "one".

We further assume that the right-shift operator applied to a negative signed integer inserts "one" bits on the left as it shifts bits off to the right.

Notice that
$$ 2^L - x = (2^L - 1) - (x - 1),$$
where $2^L - 1$ is just a string of $L$ "one" bits, and the subtraction merely cancels any "one" bits in $2^L - 1$ that align with "one" bits in $x - 1.$
There are no "borrow" operations; the result in each bit is unaffected by the bits to its right.

So you can obtain $-x$ right-shifted $N$ bits (for $N\geq 0$) as follows:

On one line write the bits of $2^{L + N}-1,$ that is, a string of $L + N$ "one" bits.

On the line below, write the bits of $x - 1$, with the last bit under the last bit of the line above.

On the third line, write the difference $(2^{L + N}-1) - (x - 1).$

Shift all three lines $N$ bits to the right; that is, erase the rightmost $N$ columns of bits.

You now have one line containing the bits of $2^L - 1$ (a string of $L$ "one" bits),
the line below containing the bits of $\left\lfloor \dfrac{x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor$,
and the third line containing the bits of $-x$ shifted $N$ bits to the right;
but the third line is also the difference of the first two lines,

$$ (2^L - 1) - \left\lfloor \dfrac{x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor. $$

We write this as

$$ 2^L - \left( \left\lfloor \dfrac{x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor + 1 \right), $$

which is the two's-complement representation in $L$ bits of the negative number

$$ - \left( \left\lfloor \dfrac{x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor + 1 \right). $$

That proves the formula for positive $x.$

If $x$ is **not** positive, then $-x$ is non-negative and shifting $-x$ right by $N$ bits has exactly the same result as shifting an unsigned binary integer right by $N$ bits, that is, the result is

$$ \left \lfloor \frac {-x}{2^N} \right\rfloor. $$

Note that
$$ \left \lfloor \frac {-x}{2^N} \right\rfloor
 = - \left \lceil \frac {x}{2^N} \right\rceil, $$
and as we have already shown,
$$ \left \lceil \frac {x}{2^N} \right\rceil = 
   \left \lfloor \frac {x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor + 1. $$

Therefore the result of shifting $-x$ right by $N$ bits is
$$ -\left(\left \lfloor \frac {x - 1}{2^N} \right\rfloor + 1\right). $$

That proves the formula for non-positive $x.$

---

I would just like to point out here that what all these formulas come down to is the simple fact that if $y$ is a binary integer, then the result of shifting $y$ to the right $N$ bits (for $N\geq 0$) is

$$ \left \lfloor \frac {y}{2^N} \right\rfloor, $$

which is relatively obvious if $y \geq 0$ and only slightly less obvious
(but still true) if $y < 0.$
I think this is the simplest way of representing a right-shift for either positive or negative binary integers.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $$\left \lfloor \dfrac{x-1}{2^N} \right \rfloor +1 = \left \lceil \dfrac{x}{2^N} \right \rceil$$ works for any number $x$ satisfying $k \cdot2^N<x< (k+1)\cdot 2^{N}$ (where $k$ is an integer), as when the number $x$ is strictly in that range, the floor and the ceil is different by 1. To be clearer, the left-hand side will always give you $k +1$ as $$k \cdot2^N<x< (k+1)\cdot 2^{N}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow k \cdot2^N + 1 \leq x < (k+1)\cdot 2^{N}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow k \leq \dfrac{x-1}{2^N} < \dfrac{(k+1)\cdot 2^{N}-1}{2^N} < k+1$$
$$\Rightarrow \left \lfloor \dfrac{x-1}{2^N} \right \rfloor = k$$
and the right-hand side will give you $k+1$, too

Let examine the case when $x=k \cdot 2^N$, the left-hand side will give us $k-1+1=k$, and the result in the right-hand side is clearly $k$.

Comment: As I understood you are saying that there are some values that will not work for this formula. Is it correct?

Comment: @NoNameQA This is a proof that the formula is correct for every integer $x.$

Comment: @NoNameQA actually I proved that every value works. I just divided it into 2 cases, ```x = k.2^N``` and ```x != k.2^N```